# Char * pointer initialization

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)

If I have the following code

```
char *str = "Tryout" ;
```

where is the string going to be stored? Stack? If stack, does the pointer point to a stack location then?

Comment: Please avoid asking questions regarding both C and C++, they are not the same language and differ in sometimes subtle ways.

Comment: yes but the above is applicable to both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string has a static storage class, (likely in read only data) and `str` is a local variable with automatic storage. This is why it is better declared as `const char *`.

Comment: It's not in automatic storage! It's in static storage.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The `str` variable is automatic whereas the string it points to is static storage :)